# Stop my front brake lever screws from vibrating out?

Tags: maintenance, brakes

One of the most common maintenance tasks on my Mongoose Tyax Super is to tighten a small screw in my front brake level. It shakes loose both due to use, and from a habit I picked up riding in Cambodia, where I "tick tick tick" the level as a subtle alternative to ringing a bell when passing pedestrians.

I assume that I could use loctite or some tap/adhesive, but I'd still like to be able to remove/clean/replace this screw. I like to adjust it between downhill and commute (I like less travel and more give on downhill). Any tips? Cheap solutions, and retail solutions?

Comment: There are several "flavors" of Loctite, including an "adjustable" variety.  This may be hard to find, but an auto parts place or well-stocked hardware store may have it.  Or you could use an adhesive that doesn't fully harden.  (And rather than doing "tick tick tick", call out "On your left!" or "Passing!" -- much more effective, and easier on the hardware.)

Comment: Red loctite is "permanent" high strength which requires some heat (say a hot air blower) to release. Blue loctite is adjustable medium strength. There are other flavours too. But get some of the blue kind, which I think is the most common.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Loctite Blue 242](http://www.loctiteproducts.com/p/10/15/t_lkr_blue/overview/Loctite-Threadlocker-Blue-242.htm) is a light duty, adjustable, and removable loctite designed for jobs like this one. It will prevent vibration from loosening your screws without preventing the adjustment you need for your brakes.

Answer (score 3):

While I would go with @zenbike's answer of the Loctite Blue first, if you wanted an alternative you could also use something for an adjustable locknut, similar to most brake lever cable adjusters (shown below). This has the benefit of being able to be adjusted (and resecured) by your fingers, instead of carrying an allen wrench with you to overcome the loctite.

[image: Brake Lever Adjustment Knobs]

It sounds like you're talking about the lever stop adjustment, but the same concept would apply; thread a small nut over it that would secure the smaller screw against the lever.

[This lever](http://www.bombayharbor.com/productImage/0877076001159261420/Bicycle_Parts_Brake_Lever.jpg) uses a spring to keep the screw in place, but in my experience they always vibrate loose anyway. Go with loctite or a locknut.

Comment: This is a better answer than just loctite because it addresses the fundamental mechanics and chemicals aren't always available.